# gradient cannot be back propagated due to comparison operator in Pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, gradient

gradient cannot be back propagated due to comparison operator in Pytorch.

My code is:

```
x=torch.tensor([1.0,1.0], requires_grad=True)
print(x)
y=(x>0.1).float().sum()
print(y)
y.backward()
print(x.grad)
```

It gives an error:

```
RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn
```

However, if i change > to +, it works.
How can I backpropagate the gradients across the comparison operator?

Answer (score 1):

Because the function is non-differentiable. In fact it's not even continuous.

Just look at this:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2783108/continuous-discontinuous-differential-and-non-differentiable-function-graph-pro

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to calculate gradient across comparison operator because

(x>y).float() is equal to step(x-y). since step function has gradient 0 at x=/0 and inf at x=0, it is meaningless. :(